# Kotlin vararg: used in a simple function and it returns some garbage

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have a simple greet function I copied from a tutorial

```
    fun sayHello(greeting:String, vararg itemsToGreet:String){
    itemsToGreet.forEach { itemToGreet ->
        println("$greeting $itemsToGreet")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val interestingThings = arrayOf("Kotlin" , "Programming", "Free Hotspot")
    sayHello("Hi" , *interestingThings)
}
```

Expected:

```
Hi Kotlin
Hi Programming
Hi Free Hotspot
```

Returns:

```
Hi [Ljava.lang.String;@7291c18f
Hi [Ljava.lang.String;@7291c18f
Hi [Ljava.lang.String;@7291c18f
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a small typo, instead of

```
println("$greeting $itemsToGreet")
```

it should be

```
println("$greeting $itemToGreet") *
```

So at the moment you are printing out the array each time which doesn't have a string representation, hence the garbage.

---

* If you haven't spotted it, the difference is the plural on `items`.